# sending mail on a windows 10 machine using Thunderbird fails

Tags: thunderbird, imap

About a month ago, my wife's computer running Windows 10 with all of the latest patches,lost the ability to send mail with attachments. Generally if the attachment is rather small in size, the progress indicator will hang at about 40%, while when I tried a 2 meg jpg it stopped at 10%. Waiting for about a minute or so does not help, though occasionally, that failed transmission which was cancelled will appear at the destination, a day or two later. She uses Thunderbird for her mail agent. I've tried turning off Microsoft defender, but that did not help. I checked all Thunderbird settings which have not changed. She uses Google connecting with Imap. I tried de-installing and reinstalling Thunderbird again with no success. Can someone suggest the best way to debug the problem without re-installing windows? I set up my dual boot laptop to boot into the same version of Windows 10 using all the same Thunderbird and server settings with no problems.

Thank you.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Troubleshoot mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-mode-thunderbird)?

Also, you can try to enable debug logs as described [here](https://www.lifewire.com/pop-imap-smtp-traffic-thunderbird-1173156) - maybe you'll find something.

Comment: Turning on troubleshoot mode in Thunderbird did not help. I'm going to try the second solution to see if I get more information. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I tried the second solution of turning on logging. Nothing appeared, probably because I had to hit cancel after a minute of waiting

Comment: I've tried everything I could think of, and pretty much decided to go with a "Windows refresh"

Comment: S - software 